# My user account is no longer a su, and I don't know the root password. What are my options?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, root, su

In Kubuntu 23.10, while updating my account photo in the System Settings > Users GUI, I must have accidentally changed my account type from Administrator to Standard, as I'm no longer a su. I guess when I installed the OS a few weeks ago, I never set a root password, because I don't know it.

Is there any way for me to get sudo access again? Since this is a dual boot Windows 11 machine, is it possible for me to modify files in the Linux partition from within Windows to get myself access?

Comment: Can you `sudo`?  I'm assuming you mean that `su -` is broken?

Comment: Are you sure you're not mixing up `su` and `sudo`? If you never set a root password it's more likely you should be using `sudo -s`. If you're prompted for a password, it's _your_ password you should enter

Comment: https://itsfoss.com/how-to-hack-ubuntu-password/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using some of the great advice in the comments, I followed these steps and gained access again.

1. Booted into Windows
2. Installed the Linux File Systems for Windows app by Paragon so I could mount the Linux partition and access it from Windows. (I was able to just use the free trial, but if I need it again, I'd be willing to pay for it since it got the job done. WSL currently requires that the partition being mounted be a different physical drive than the NTFS partition Windows is installed on, so I had to go with a third-party tool)
3. Opened the `/etc` directory in VS Code and compared `/etc/group-` (left) to `/etc/group` (right). Thankfully, the former contained the backup prior to my change. It's easy to see in this diff what happened.
   [image]
4. Copied the current contents of `/etc/group` into a backup file in Windows just in case, then replaced the contents of `/etc/group` with the `/etc/group-` backup.
5. Rebooted into Linux, verified I once again had sudo access, then immediately set a root password so I don't get myself into trouble again.

Answer (score 0):

Windows does not have suitable tools. You might be able to create a Linux installation on a bootable USB stick or CD/DVD and boot from that, then access the volume on which you installed Linux. This requires some experience or at least the ability to browse the internet on a separate device so that you don't need to boot into Windows just to look up some web pages.

Comment: It can have suitable tools if you install WSL. But that then mostly defeats the point of having a dual-boot system

Comment: Even without WSL, all you need to do is mount the Linux drive and fiddle with `/etc/paswd`, or `/etc/sudoers` depending on what has happened, right @ChrisDavies?

Comment: @terdon not from Windows, no, as there's no extN device driver

Comment: @ChrisDavies yes, but there are tools that let you mount ext drives. I think WSL can do it natively anyway, but [there are apps](https://www.howtogeek.com/112888/3-ways-to-access-your-linux-partitions-from-windows/) for it too. Since the fix most likely requires just editing simple text files, it _should_ be possible and relatively straightforward from Windows too as long as you get a tool to mount the drive and then make sure your text editor doesn't add windows line endings.

Comment: @terdon FYI only the commercial one (from the excellent Paragon) remains on that list. The two FOSS options are either broken or offer read-only support

Comment: @ChrisDavies ah. I know I used something like this many years ago but I really don't remember which one, but presumably since WSL can do this it is no longer needed.

Comment: @ChrisDavies @terdon Using the program from Paragon, I was able to examine `/etc/groups`. [Comparing it to `/etc/groups-`](https://i.imgur.com/bMzeTjf.png), I can see that I was removed from several groups. I think if I restore the backup by switching the names of the two files, I might get access again. Does that sound right?

Comment: It worked! Thank you, folks.